# About "Languish" and "Languishment"

Tags: nouns

I have a doubt about the following sentence: "they are experiencing their languish". Should "languish" be kept or replaced by "languishment" as in "they are experiencing their languishment"? Or are both valid?

Answer (score 1):

Native speaker here, reasonably well read, and never seen "languishment" in my life! Of course, it might well be an obscure term, but do you want to be using obscure terms here? I wouldn't even use the "languish" version either. Might be a collocation issue with "experience". I'd try something completely different with a completely different word.

Comment: I see, so languishment is obscure. Thank you very much for your input. I am doing a translation and the sentence I am having difficulties with is: "the possibility of having to experience their languish". 

You said there could be a collocation issue with "experience", correct?I want to confirm if "to live" can be used as a synonym of "to experience" For instance, "the possibility of having to live their languish". if I put it this way, does it sound better or more natural?

Comment: I'm more familiar with languish as a verb than as a noun, come to think of it. There's a common English expression "to languish in jail". In your case, I don't have the context, but suspect something on the lines of "the prospect of having to live with this guilt/loss/pain" might be better.

Comment: Hmm. You're right, languish indeed seems to be a verb (instead of a noun as I originally thought). I've had another idea. Although it wouldn't be completely authentic to the original text, do you think that, for example, "the possibility of having to languish is terrible" sounds better than "the possibility of having to live their languish is terrible"? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I am using "languish" here as a meaning of "becoming weak" especially due to old age and/or illnesses.

Comment: Yes, 'languish' is definitely a verb. You don't give the context, but if you are talking about people becoming frail you could say 'they are languishing' or 'they are in failing health'.